# How to make esp8266 receive commands from another esp8266 webserver?

Tags: webserver, esp8266, access-point

Hello could someone show me what changes need to be made to the following github code so that I can connect another esp8266 to it so that it can receive commands from the webserver?

Things that I know so far is that changing the [Server] esp8266 to AP mode so that it makes it much more convenient to connect the [Client] esp8266 to it has already been done in my code, this was straightforward to do but I've never experienced having to retrieve data from one esp8266 to another.

This link provides the original code that I have been working from, if my [server] and [client] code is needed then I can post it but they're essentially the same with exception for one being access point mode and the other coding to the access point.

https://github.com/jasoncoon/esp8266-fastled-webserver

Comment: send the same HTTP requests like the web page presented by the sketch

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try that.